# What is currently the best way to set a 3rd party cookie?

Tags: cookies, p3p

I'm reading a lot on this topic for some time now.

The information on the web about this topic is quite confusing.

Use case:
A User visits site hostA.com, which includes a **"tracking pixel"** from site hostB.com .
The user never visited hostB.com before. hostB.com sets a cookie with the response.

Which browsers will accept and save the cookie? (I read about safari does not, is this true, is this only true for iframes?)
How does default security configuration effect the challenge?
Is it enough to set a "correct" **P3P** header? (It seams to help with some Versions of the Internet Explorer)
Is there a common, accepted solution for the challenge?
Is the only why to use flash **LSOs**?

Thanks 
stephan

Comment: Most browsers have an option to allow or deny setting third party cookies. That's also how it's documented (usually). ~ However, I don't know that you CAN set a third party cookie. ~ Also, it seems like you're asking several questions here.

Comment: I think its only one question, is it possible / how to set a third party cookie. I aware of the configuration in browsers about it, but I dont know what configuration currently is and hope for the "best practice"

Answer (score 1):

You can only set cookies for the domain that the page came from (your site).  3rd party cookies are up to the user to control through their browser settings.  I never allow them in the Internet Group just for the example you gave of a "Tracking Pixel"